# Eclipse RCP 4.x show view

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm working for a short time on the libraries of eclipse 4.x  someone could tell me how can I open a view through from the context menu? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to add things to a context menu or how to show a view? Are you using an Eclipse 4 RCP with an application model or Eclipse 3.x compatibility mode.

Comment: how to show a view using Eclipse 4 but with the menu action!

Comment: Sorry in Eclipse RCP 4.x the views = the parts!

Comment: So you want to open an `MPart` from a context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a part anywhere you should define a `command` in the application model and a `handler` for the command. To show a part in the handler use:

```
@Execute
public void execute(EPartService partService)
{
  MPart mpart = partService.showPart(part id, PartState.ACTIVATE);
}
```

In the application `Part` definition for your part add a `Popup Menu` to the `Menus` section. In the popup menu define a `HandledMenuItem` for your command.

To register the popup menu as the context menu for a control (tree, table etc) use:

```
@Inject
private EMenuService;

...

menuService.registerContextMenu(control, menu id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Works!!!!! :D Could you tell me where I can find some material on Eclipse 4.x ? It is very hard for me!!!

Comment: This is the best intro: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html  There is also an e-book by the same author (extended version of the tutorial)

Comment: Sorry..... another question.... :) If I wanted to pass parameters during the creation of the part. How do I do?

Comment: The `MPart` returned by `showView` has a `getObject()` method which give you your class for the part. So you call methods on the class or run Injection on the class.

Comment: Greg.... sorry.... can you write an example of use of Injection? Sorry but for me is the first time!!! thx :)

Comment: Have a look at my second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535342/how-to-implement-save-as-functionality-for-our-part