# How to implement "Save As" functionality for our Part

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

I'm creating E4 RCP application in that I have one part. I want to implement "Save As" functionality for my Part, as it is implemented for Editors (Like:Java file Editor).

Requirements:

1. When user click on my part "Save As" option should be enable.
2. When user click on "Save As" option my code should run so that I can do what I want.

So my question is for this what should I do, is I have to implement any extension point or any this else. ?

Comment: Just to confirm - this is a 'pure' e4 application using your own application model and no Eclipse 3 compatibility code?

Comment: Hi @greg-449 i', using it with compatibility code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pure e4 application there is no built in support for Save As so you will need to code this yourself.

To be consistent with the `@Persist` support for Save I would suggest doing this with an annotation, lets call it `@PersistAs`:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PersistAs
{
}
```

You will have to add a command definition for 'save as' along with a handler and menu items in the usual way.

The handler for Save As would look something like:

```
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) final MPart part)
{
  Object client = part.getObject();
  ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(client, PersistAs.class, part.getContext());
}
```

and in your part you would have:

```
@PersistAs
public void saveAs()
{
  // You save as code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 3 compatibility mode you implement the `doSaveAs` and `isSaveAsAllowed` methods in your `EditorPart`.